# missing file in installed deb package (customized dockerized debian)

Tags: docker, apt

I need to achieve ldap + kerberos integration. 
The docker image I'm using for the ldap side is: https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

Currently I'm following: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kerberos-ldap.html
however I'm stuck, there seems to be missing file: `/usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz`.

Running:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -yy && apt-get install -yy  krb5-kdc-ldap && ls -l /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz
```

Inside the container: `osixia/openldap:1.1.2` there is no such file. Any idea why it is so?

however if I run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -yy apt-file && apt-file update && apt-file list krb5-kdc-ldap
```

I see:

```
krb5-kdc-ldap: /etc/insserv/overrides/krb5-kdc
krb5-kdc-ldap: /lib/systemd/system/krb5-admin-server.service.d/slapd-before-kdc.conf
krb5-kdc-ldap: /lib/systemd/system/krb5-kdc.service.d/slapd-before-kdc.conf
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/krb5/libkdb_ldap.so.1
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/krb5/libkdb_ldap.so.1.0
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/krb5/plugins/kdb/kldap.so
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/sbin/kdb5_ldap_util
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/NEWS.Debian.gz
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/changelog.Debian.gz
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/copyright
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.ldif.gz
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz
krb5-kdc-ldap: /usr/share/man/man8/kdb5_ldap_util.8.gz
```

moreover, if I run the command inside the `debian:jessie` docker container:

```
   apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -yy && apt-get install -yy  krb5-kdc-ldap && ls -l /usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz
```

I can see the file present.

How is it, that after installation of the package one of it's file is missing in the specific container?
And how can I get the file: `kerberos.schema.gz` in the container: `osixia/openldap:1.1.2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, this documentation error already has a [solution](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/issues/57), I quote:

> this image had a configuration to prevent documentation and locales to be installed to make it more lightweight as possible.
>
> To install doc remove the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nodoc`
>
> ```
> rm -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nodoc
> ```
>
> and to install locales remove `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nolocales`
>
> ```
> rm -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nolocales
> ```
>
> After that install `krb5-kdc-ldap` and `/usr/share/doc/krb5-kdc-ldap/kerberos.schema.gz` file should be there.

Answer (score 0):

The .gz part of the filename looks likely to mean some form of compression was used in creating it, such as gzip.  If so, you might try adding an uncompressed version of the file, with the same name except without the .gz part, to the same directory.

Also, you could read through the installation process, to see if it downloads that file, uses it, and then deletes it.

Comment: not sure what you mean with: 'adding an uncompressed version of the file'. It's a debian package I'm installing it's not about manually adding particular file. Moreover regarding installation process, well doesn't list the files unpacked for me.